# Swift: Function call from custom class throws exception

Tags: swift, exception

I have a cusom class for NSButton. Pressing the button calls a function in the main AppDelegate.swift by `AppDelegate().startTask()`, which fires an NSTask and animates an NSProgressIndicator via IBOutlet in AppDelegate.swift.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySpinner: NSProgressIndicator!

func startTask() -> Void
{
    mySpinner.startAnimation(true)
    ...
}
```

It throws an error at `mySpinner.startAnimation(true)`:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

What am I missing? Does AppDelegate not have access to this IBOutlet when called from a custom class? Calling this function from within AppDelegate works fine.

Comment: You should call this function after viewDidLoad, the view didn't load yet so mySpinner is nil

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The solution given by appzYourLife was the missing part - see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

With this line

```
AppDelegate().startTask()
```

you are creating a new `AppDelegate`. In this new instance `mySpinner` is not populated and this line does crash

```
mySpinner.startAnimation(true)
```

because `mySpinnder` is `nil`.

### Solution

You should instead retrieve the instance of AppDelegate already created

```
let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.startTask()
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem and explained it well.